Using find function to extract text
I have a column that sometimes apear the word "IMEI" on it, like this: "MOTO G 52 AZUL IMEI 357138167548897". So I need a formula that find the word "IMEI" and bring me the number after it.

You can use the regular expression match function to extract the data you're looking for.
From the column with the IMEI text in, select Edit Column > Add column based on this column, and then enter something like the function below to extract the data. This is a regular expression that looks for "IMEI" followed by a space, and then extracts any sequence of digits following it.
value.match(/.*IMEI ([0-9]+).*/)[0]

You may need to adjust the regular expression depending on the exact format of data in your column.

